# How to add top bar header in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a website and need to add top bar header for some text, date and time.

Are there any plugins to do this or how I custom my header for this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not using your own custom theme. I would start out by creating a child theme which is the recommended way of modifying an existing premium theme. This will allow you to modify the header.php file so when the parent theme is updated, your changes will not be overwritten.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

After you create your new child theme with the style.css and functions.php files, you'll need to copy over header.php from parent to child. Not sure what the header.php file looks like but if you add in something similar to the code below, it should work:

```
<ul>
    <li>Here is some text</li>
    <li>Today is <?php echo date_i18n( "F j, Y, g:i a" ); ?></li>
</ul>
```